# Back button event does not fire Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, back-button, angular-route-segment

I am trying to redirect the user to a particular url on the click of back button in browser, and here is the code

```
constructor(private router: Router,private location: PlatformLocation) {        
        let eventUrl = window.sessionStorage.getItem('Event');
        this.location.onPopState(() => {
            alert('click');
            this.router.navigate(['/', this.selectedLanguage, 'event', eventUrl]);
        });
    }
```

but it does not seem to fire the event when user click on back button. The code is in the current component. what is the issue?

**EDIT**

I tried with the below answer suggested, but that too does not seems to work, the function getting called , but it still redirects to the previous page rather than the mentioned url below

```
unload(event: any) {
        let eventUrl = window.sessionStorage.getItem('buyerEvent');
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/' + this.selectedLanguage + '/event/' + eventUrl);
    }
```

Comment: why is the code of back button inside the constructor ?

Comment: This is browser's back button

Comment: sorry my bad i was on phone didn't read it properly

Comment: Any error in console

Comment: no error in console.

Comment: just for check have you imorted `import { PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common'`

Comment: yeah its there too

Comment: can u create a plunker replicating the issue as it works for me locally

Comment: The event won't trigger **only if** you are leaving your app after click `back` button.

Comment: @Pengyy That makes sense, in this case i want to redirect to a url

Comment: @Sajeetharan I have once tried with `@HostListener('window.unload')` to open a specific url in new tab.

Comment: @Pengyy can you post an answer with sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind things you want to do while leaving the app to `window.unload` event. Here I used the `HostListener`.

```
@HostListener('window: unload', ['$event'])
unload(event) {
  window.open('https://localhost:4200', '_blank');
  window.close();
}
```

---

Mention that Chrome will block `window.open` by default, you have to change block policy.

Comment: @Sajeetharan I just confirmed at my local app and it's working fine. BTW, I test by locating above code at `AppComponent`, but this shouldn't matter I think.

Comment: the function is getting invoked , but it does not redirect to a different url. it goes back to the stripe window which was the previous one in this case

Comment: @Sajeetharan `window.open` will open the different url in a new tab, and `window.close` will close the current tab. This is for your specific requirement.

Comment: @Sajeetharan Also make sure that you are opening the url in **new tab**, for some reason it won't work when you try to open it in current tab.

Answer (score -1):

I'm use Location

```
Import { Location } from '@angular/common';
```

declare on constructor

```
constructor(private _location: Location){}
```

and make a function

```
backClicked() {
    this._location.back();
}
```

then set it into button

```
<button (click)="backClicked()"> TEAM FALL BACK</button>
```

Then watch the magic happen ...

Comment: button is browser's one

Comment: this.checkRouter.navigateByUrl('/'); so try navigateByUrl to your code